# Cannot associate models properly following Rails guides

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the Rails guides, but I'm getting stuck where I add a comment to my post (which I'm calling record)

[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-posts)

I do as they say, and my server output is:

```
Started POST "/records/2/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-28 01:28:27 +0100
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"XC40jP5Sh6Chr3uXGoSny04n6KJI6+o8LR+txA6cE1o=", "comment"=>  {"body"=>"aaa"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "record_id"=>"2"}
Record Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` WHERE `records`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `records` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-02-28 00:28:27', '2014-02-28 00:28:27')
(6.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/records/2
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
```

Now, I think I have followed the guide pretty closely... my controller is:

```
   @record = Record.find(params[:record_id])
   @comment = @record.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
   redirect_to record_path(@record)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE: here is my schema for record and comment

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
 t.text     "body"
 t.integer  "record_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "records", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.string   "surname"
 t.integer  "weight"
 t.integer  "desired_weight"
 t.integer  "height"
 t.date     "dob"
 t.string   "city"
 t.string   "condition"
 t.string   "allergy"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "avatar_file_name"
 t.string   "avatar_content_type"
 t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
 t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
end
```

add_index "comments", ["record_id"], name: "index_comments_on_record_id", using: :btree

UPDATE: Taken from Rails guides, here is my controller

```
@record = Record.find(params[:record_id])
@comment = @record.comments.create!(params[:comment].permit(:body))
redirect_to record_path(@record)
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of Record and Comments.

Comment: Schema looks alright. Can you share the complete `create` action of CommentsController.

Comment: The code that you have shown, is it `CommentsController` `create` action? You just mention `my controller` and not the controller name.  I am checking because as per logs that you shared, a `record` is being created in database and in the code that you shared a `comment` is getting created but no `record`. You see the mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing the code

```
@record = Record.find(params[:record_id])
@comment = @record.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
```

using the Rails Console?  Also if you try with

```
create!()
```

instead of

```
create()
```

Then you can determine if there any any exceptions which are raised; due either to validations you have on the model, or attributes which haven't ben specified.

Comment: I think it is not saving a comment ID #<Comment id: nil, body: "test", record_id: 31, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: Agree.  From the RailsGuides on create it says that the once all validations are passed then the associated object is saved. In this case the comment.

Answer (score -1):

I believe `permit` accept a Array, and also you should use the `require` statement. So try changing:

```
@comment = @record.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
```

into:

```
@comment = @record.comments.create(params.require(:comment).permit([:body]))
```

Note its a good idea to create a private method to cover permited attributes, like this:

```
class MyController

  def create
    ...
    @comment = @record.comments.create(comment_params)
    ...
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit([:body])
    end

end
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Also try to restart your server after your changes (normally not needed, but it's just in case)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm still getting the same issue, it just feels like nothing is being written

Comment: `permit` accepts splat arguments. Check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit